# Operaciones con jerarquia de datos java

Tags: java

Muy buenas a todos, me podrian ayudar con esto porfavor (es en java):
Realizar un programa que pueda resolver operaciones como SUMA, RESTA, MULTIPLICACION y DIVISION tomando en cuenta la la jerarquia de operaciones ejemplo:
Entrada: 2 + 4 * 5
Salida: 22

Entrada 5 * ( 1 + 2 )
Salida 15

psdt: intente realizando el programa como cualquier operacion que pida datos pero no se como o que utilizar para que respete la jerarquia.

Comment: Hola, Manuel. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir el código con lo qué has intentado, cuál ha sido el problema que se te ha presentado, el error, etc?

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste, saludos.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que tienes para poder revisarlo

Comment: La utilización de paréntesis es muy importante  en la jerarquia de datos cuando quieres proceder a realizar operaciones ya que sirven para aislar una porción de la expresión de forma que el cálculo se ejecute de forma independiente. Si quitamos los paréntesis el compilador protestará.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo asi.

```
public class Calculos{
    int suma;
    int resta;
    int multiplicacion;
    int division;

    //Métodos
    public void sumar(int numero1, int numero2){
        suma = numero1 + numero2;
    }
    public void restar(int numero1, int numero2){
        // IGUAL QUE LA SUMA
    }
    public void multiplicar(int numero1, int numero2){
        // IGUAL QUE LA SUMA
    }
    public void dividir(int numero1, int numero2){
        // IGUAL QUE LA SUMA
    }
    public void mostrar(){
    System.out.println("suma = " + suma);
    System.out.println("Resta = " + resta);
    System.out.println("Multiplicación = " + multiplicacion);
    System.out.println("División = " + division);

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1 = 10;
        int n2 = 2;
       Operacion op1 = new Operacion();
       op1.sumar(n1,n2);
       op1.restar(n1,n2);
       op1.multiplicar(n1,n2);
       op1.dividir(n1,n2);
       op1.mostrar();
    } 
}
```

Deberas hacerlo uno a uno y apuntarte el resultado para la suma del +2

Comment: Y la jerarquía de operaciones?

Comment: eso ya no se como va losiento